# Can I use an Ant fileset as input to construct another fileset?

Tags: ant

I am automating a build process using Jenkins and Ant build steps.  I have the build operation and post-build source control tagging working fine.

After a number of QT projects have been built, I want to be able to preserve the useful artifacts from the build.

As a vehicle for discussion/consideration, lets say I have the following set of files in a build directory:

```
MyApp.exe
MyApp.pdb
MyApp_Tests.exe
MyApp_Tests.pdb
SomeLib.lib
SomeLib.pdb
3rdParty.lib
3rdParty.pdb
Utils.dll
Utils.pdb
```

(In reality there are many more exe's, dll's lib's and their associated pdb files and the files produced by the build change frequently as the project evolves.)

I want to collect the "deliverable" files (non-test exe's and dll's) and their pdb files **without** the test exe's, lib files and their pdb files.

I believe I can get a fileset of the deliverable files to use in a copy task:

```
<copy todir="${artifactDestination}" failonerror="true">
    <fileset dir="./build">
        <include name="*.exe" />
        <include name="*.dll" />
        <exclude name="*_Tests*" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

What I am struggling with is how to get a fileset of the pdb files that relate to the exe and dll files, i.e. all the pdb files except MyApp_Tests.pdb, SomeLib.pdb and 3rdParty.pdb.

What I would like to do is use the initial fileset of exe and dll files and create a second fileset from that which has those filenames with a .pdb extension instead of .dll or .exe.

I've been reading up on selectors and such but have not managed to spot a solution to achieve my desired result.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want with two subsequent `copy` tasks. The first one is the one you've already figured out. In order to copy the `.pdb` files that match the files you've copied in the first step you can use a `present` selector.

```
<copy todir="${artifactDestination}" failonerror="true">
  <fileset dir="build">
    <or>
      <present targetdir="${artifactDestination}">
        <globmapper from="*.pdb" to="*.exe"/>
      </present>
      <present targetdir="${artifactDestination}">
        <globmapper from="*.pdb" to="*.dll"/>
      </present>
    </or>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: I had tried using `globmapper` within a second copy but had only achieved copying the first file to the destination with the different file extension.  Looks like I was thinking along (almost) the right lines, but your proposal is exactly what I needed.  Thanks @StefanBodewig